# Find the position of the minimal value of a three dimensional array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

Sorry for asking such a simple and silly question, but Matlab is really too hard to use for me. My question is just how to find the position the minimal value of a three dimensional array in Matlab.

For example, suppose I define a three dimensional array

```
m=zeros(2,2,2);
m(1,2,2)=-2;
```

The minimal value of `m` should be `-2`, located at `(1,2,2)`. I can find the minimal value by

```
m0=min(min(min(m)));
```

But when I find its position by using

```
[x y z]=find(m==m0);
```

Instead of returning `x=1`, `y=2` and `z=2`, it returns `x=1`, `y=4` and `z=1`.

I appreciate if anyone would answer this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`min`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) to find the minimum index of `m` and then convert it to `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates. There is **no** need to use `find` also.

[`min`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) can be used with multiple output arguments to return the index of the minimum element. Here, I also use [`:`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) to return every element of `m` as a column vector.

```
>> m=zeros(2,2,2);
>> m(1,2,2)=-2;
>> m(:)
ans =
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
    -2
     0
>> [~, ind] = min(m(:))
ind =
     7
```

Now we have our index we need to convert it back into `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates. This can be done using [`ind2sub`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) or manually by hand.

```
>> [x y z] = ind2sub(size(m), ind)
x =
     1
y =
     2
z =
     2
```

Comment: +1  I knew about the `[val, ind]` version of `min`, but I didn't think to use it with the column vector `m(:)`.  This is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct.  This is more complicated than it should be.  The problem is that `MATLAB` is hardwired to work with matrices (i.e. arrays of rank 2), rather than arrays of general rank.  Here's the solution:

```
m0 = min(m(:))
[x y z] = ind2sub(size(m), find(m(:) == m0))
```

Explanation:

If you type `help find`, you may notice that your original code was using the `[rows, cols, vals]` version of `find`, which is not what you expected.

Instead, `min(m(:))` is a simplification of your `min(min(min(m)))`.  It automatically reshapes `m` into a rank one array (i.e. a vector).

The expression `find(m(:) == m0)` returns a single index for the minimum position in this reshaped vector.  Finally, `ind2sub` converts this single index into a set of three indices, given the shape of `m`.